# Android global array string

Tags: android

i write simple android application with two method:
i define a simple string array in this line:

```
public class breakactivity extends Activity {
    String[] id;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
```

and into this method:

```
public void fill(){
         id=new String[30];
         id[0]="x1";
         id[1]="x2";
}
```

and i want fetch the id array data into android onCreate method for example:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            string temp=id[0];
}
```

How can solve that?thanks for all.

Comment: please post what you have already tried

Comment: i want fill the data into the fill method,and fetch array data into onCreate method

Comment: yes but according to your post you have done something, so what the problem is there ? is it working ? any errors you got ??

Comment: when i use id[0] into onCreate method,i get thid error,Array type expected:found 'long'

Comment: post your  whole source code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a method called `fill()` now you have to call it in `onCreate()`

```
public class breakactivity extends Activity {
    String[] id;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            fill();
            String temp = id[0];
    }
    public void fill(){
         id = new String[30];
         id[0] = "x1";
         id[1] = "x2";
    }
}
```

Comment: in string temp=id[0] i get this error:Array type expected;found 'long'